# Animation don't stop on variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, delay

Why is the percentage not stopping after the first animation. That being, right after the filling bar.

```
$('.perctext').delay(1500).each(
     function(a)
       $(this).delay(a*250).animate({
     'left':width
  },1000);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/helionbc/EzqLd/)

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

SOLUTION: Check the answer from Blender bellow. 
[FIDDLE WITH SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/helionbc/EzqLd/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're querying the DOM each time for elements that match your selector, so the first bar matches one element with a class of `perctext`, the second bar matches the previous bar's percentage text element and its own, and the third bar matches all three.

Store the created element in a variable and animate only that specific one

```
var $perctext = $('<div>', {'class': 'perctext', text: width});
$perctext.appendTo(this);

$perctext.delay(1500).each(function(a) {
    $(this).delay(a * 250).animate({
        'left': width
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: How did I miss that. You're totally right. Thank you very much for the quick answer.